# How to access nodes in xml in php

Tags: php, xml

I have the following xml schema but i don't know how to access this in php. please help me in accessing it.

here is the samples structure

```
<PropertyDetails>
   <ListingID>listingid</ListingID>
   <AgentDetails ID="13245">
      <Name>Agent Name One</Name>
      <Phones>
         <Phone ContactType="Business" PhoneType="Telephone">123-45678</Phone>

      </Phones>
      <Office ID="65">
         <Name>BROKER</Name>
         <Address>
            <StreetAddress>17 Z STREET</StreetAddress>
            <AddressLine1>1 T STREET</AddressLine1>
            <City>BE</City>
            <PostalCode>142001</PostalCode>
         </Address>
         <Phones>
            <Phone ContactType="Business" PhoneType="Telephone">123-45678</Phone>
            <Phone ContactType="Business" PhoneType="Fax">123-45678</Phone>
         </Phones>
         <Websites>
            <Website ContactType="Business" WebsiteType="Website">www</Website>
         </Websites>
      </Office>
      <Designations>
         <Designation>BRD</Designation>
      </Designations>
   </AgentDetails>
   <AgentDetails ID="163">
      <Name>Agent Name Two</Name>
      <Phones>
         <Phone ContactType="Business" PhoneType="Telephone">(103) 321-134</Phone>
         <Phone ContactType="Business" PhoneType="Fax">(603) 132-1222</Phone>
      </Phones>
      <Office ID="27">
         <Name>HRC, BR</Name>
         <Address>
            <StreetAddress>1 N STREET</StreetAddress>
            <AddressLine1>7 P STREET</AddressLine1>
            <City>BE</City>
            <PostalCode>142001</PostalCode>
         </Address>
         <Phones>
            <Phone ContactType="Business" PhoneType="Telephone">123 6578</Phone>
            <Phone ContactType="Business" PhoneType="Fax">321-134</Phone>
         </Phones>
      </Office>
      <Designations>
         <Designation>BR</Designation>
      </Designations>
   </AgentDetails>
   </PropertyDetails>
```

in php

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("seven.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
echo 'Agent Details'.$xml['AgentDetails']->Name;
```

at above line it gives me error Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\cr\services\create.php on line 3

I am new in accessing xml in php. please help.

Comment: And what is the question now?

Comment: @Rizier123 please see the Notice in the end of question

Comment: Are you asking how to access the Agent Details name?

Comment: I have to access all the elemens. The agent name was just the beginning. I just want to know the way to access any of its elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simple access it as a normal object like this:

```
echo 'Agent Details: '.$xml->AgentDetails[0]->Name;
```

Output:

```
Agent Details: Agent Name One
```

If you want to see the structure of your variable (object) just do this and you will see how to access it:

```
print_r($xml);
```

Also for more information about simplexml_load_file() see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php

Comment: @Rizier13 thanks. if i have to access phone number will this work echo 'Agent Phone Number'.$xml->AgentDetails[0]->phones[0]->phone;

Comment: @user2299040 Almost, it would be: `echo 'Agent Details '.$xml->AgentDetails[0]->Phones->Phone;` Because: `AgentDetails` Is a array, so you try to access index 0 (`[0]`), Index 0 is a SimpleXMLElement Object And you want to access the property `Phones`, which is also a object where you want to access the property `Phone`